# Why Flurry Analytics said "NO DATA"?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics, no-data

When I accessed Flurry Analytics on April 28th, it said there was "NO DATA", and I was unable to check the log.
I tried using several different accounts but the situation was the same.

After that I tried again using the same method on April 30th and was able to check the log as usual.

I would like you to advise why I was unable to see any data on April 28th, and if there is going to be any periodical maintenance etc. in the future.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was the result of an outage due to code released the previous day causing the event logs to be inaccessible for approximately 18 hours. We do not expect any reoccurrence of this issue.